# Managing ruby in different locations on development and production servers

Tags: ruby, rvm, bluehost

looking for some recommendations on best practices here.

I've been tinkering with a small CGI script. I have RVM installed via Homebrew on my Macbook Air.

I was using the old `#! /usr/bin/env ruby` trick in my script, which worked fine on my local development environment because I configured all the `PATH`s to use RVM ruby.

However, when I deploy on the production web host (Bluehost), I must use their ruby located in the standard location at `/usr/bin/ruby`.

How should I set up my development environment so that I can maintain the same shebang link between development and production? I thought of symlinking `/usr/bin/ruby` on my local development machine to RVM, and then using the `#! /usr/bin/ruby` in all my scripts, but that seems like a dirty hack which would not be easily maintained as I swap between different rubies.

Has anyone else run into this problem? If so, was there a graceful way to manage it? Thx.

Comment: The first thing is, don't use CGI. Instead, use something modern like Sinatra, Padrino or Rails. You'll find any of those three are years ahead of CGI and any work you do in CGI will be a distant relative to the others, where they are more closely related. In other words, what you learn with CGI won't transfer easily to something more modern and you'll have to start over later to learn the current technologies. If you're trying to understand the basics of how web works, Sinatra will put you closer to the metal than Rails and is a great starting point.

Comment: @the-Tin-Man Rails and Sinatra aren't appropriate for what I am working on, which is a simple form mailer for a web page. Building that in Sinatra or Rails would add significant extra complexity.

If I were to build a more advanced web site/application, then yes I would use Sinatra or Rails as you recommend.